# Не могу удалить юзера в postgres

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Как удалить пользователя в `postgres`?

Устанавливаю соединение с *postgres*:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

Удаляю юзера, но не получается:

```
postgres=# drop user test_user;
ERROR:  role "test_user" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL:  privileges for database postgres
```

Выдаю список всех таблиц:

```
postgres=# \dt
              List of relations
 Schema |      Name       | Type  |  Owner   
--------+-----------------+-------+----------
 public | groupped_points | table | postgres
 public | point1          | table | postgres
 public | points          | table | postgres
 public | polygon1        | table | postgres
 public | polygons        | table | postgres
 public | spatial_ref_sys | table | postgres
 public | temp_points     | table | postgres
 public | test            | table | postgres
(8 rows)
```

Как видим, ни одна таблица не связана с *test_user*. Выдаю список юзеров:

```
postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 test_user |
```

В чём может быть проблема? С чем может быть ещё связан *test_user*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> because some objects depend on it

Объекты в БД - это очень-очень далеко не только таблички. А ещё сами базы, schema в них, права, sequence, функции, триггеры, view, tablespace, другие роли и пользователи и всякое прочее.

[При удалении](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_10_STABLE/src/backend/commands/user.c#L1057) пользователя проверяется [список зависимостей](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_10_STABLE/src/backend/catalog/pg_shdepend.c#L501) по системному каталогу [`pg_shdepend`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/catalog-pg-shdepend.html). Переводя к языку SQL, выполняется вот такой запрос:

```
select * 
from pg_shdepend 
where refclassid = 'pg_authid'::regclass 
  and refobjid = (
    select oid from pg_roles where rolname = 'someuser'
  );
```

Собственно, в `detail` сообщении об ошибке попутно пишется список (возможно усечённый, в `checkSharedDependencies` есть лимит в 100 элементов) тех вещей, с которыми конфликтует удаление. В вашем случае вполне явно была указана подсказка

> DETAIL:  privileges for database postgres

То есть удалить пользователя не дают выданные привилегии в базе `postgres`.

Для моего пользователя, например, выводятся:

```
ERROR:  role "melkij" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL:  owner of database melkij
owner of database dbname
99 objects in database melkij
6 objects in database dbname
```

То есть пользователь владелец пары баз и имеет там некоторые объекты в большом числе.

Для каждого типа объекта будут нужны свои команды для смены владельца или удаления. Так же есть две специальные команды:

- [`DROP OWNED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-drop-owned.html) - которая удаляет соответствующие объекты. Поаккуратнее с этим, удаление всё-таки.
- [`REASSIGN OWNED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-reassign-owned.html) - которая передаёт владение объектов какой-то другой роли.

Важно заметить, что обе команды работают на уровне только одной БД. Удаление пользователя же требует отсутствия объектов во всех БД - то есть необходимо пройти по всем БД.

---

Иногда бывает проще сделать дамп схемы кластера `pg_dumpall -s` и поискать упоминания пользователя в нём.

Answer (score 1):

Решение проблемы простое и тривиальное. Необходимо было забрать все права у юзера:

```
REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE postgres FROM test_user;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public FROM test_user;
```

После этого делаем:

```
drop user test_user;
```

Смотрим на юзеров:

```
postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

Юзер удалён.

*Замечание*. Дать права можно аналогично:

```
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE postgres TO test_user;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO test_user;
```